# Uncaught ReferenceError: photoModule is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuex

`Uncaught ReferenceError: photoModule is not defined`

Еhe first time I encountered such an error so that the vuex store does not find the module.

What could be the problem?

**vuex**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({

modules: {
photoModule
}
})
```

**main.js**

```
import store from './store'

Vue.prototype.axios = axios


Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**photoModule**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    state: {
        photos: []
    },
    mitations: {
        setPhotos(state, payload) {
            state.photos = payload
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getAllPhotos(state) {
            return state.photos
        }
    },
    actions: {
        fetchPhotos(context) {
      
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_limit=10')
.then(response => this.photos = context.commit('setPhotos', response.data))
       
}
}
}
```

For the second day I have been sitting on this error. At least hint where something is wrong

Comment: Most likely the typo in `mitations`

Comment: brombeer nope (((   photoModule is not defined

Answer (score 2):

You didn't import the module

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import photoModule from './photoModule.js'  // ✅ Add this

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    photoModule
  }
})
```